# batch file - results in one line

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

How can i write batch file that stores result in a file in just one line?

> echo %computername% >> c:\out.txt
>
> wmic datafile where name='c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe' get
>   lastmodified >> c:\out.txt

I want result to be in txt.txt file like this:

> xxx yyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to double slashes in wmi query.And you need to wrap the WMIC command in two FOR loops to purge the result.For one line result use /format:value

```
@echo off
echo|set /p=%computername%>out.txt
for /f "delims=" %%T in ('"wmic datafile where name='c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe' get lastmodified /format:value"') do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%A in ("%%T") do (echo %%B)>>out.txt 
)
```

you can add `%%A` before `%%B` if you want the `lastmodified` string.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
< nul (set /p s=%computername%) > c:\out.txt
wmic datafile where name='c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe' get lastmodified /format:value >> c:\out.txt
```